# PyQt4 ScrollArea widget issues: Scrollbar not working correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm writing a program in python 2.7 with PyQt4 and i'm having the following problem with the scrollArea widget. As seen in the images below, the scrollbar is not working correctly. Its not moving the graph at all. The scrollbar in the middle is showing the same thing as in the original position.

scroll bar at original position

[image: scroll bar at original position]

scroll bar almost in the middle

[image: scroll bar almost in the middle]

I've already try the program in others computers with differents SO and got the same result, which means the problem is the code. The program is too long so i'll just show where the scroll area widget is being called.

```
class graphWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(graphWidget, self).__init__()
        self.graph=CreateGraphFromInputs.createGraph()
        self.slider=QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        #slider setup#
        self.slider.setMinimum(1)
        self.slider.setMaximum(20)
        self.slider.setValue(1)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(1)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderValueChange)
        self.zoomLabel=QtGui.QLabel(str(self.slider.value())+"x")
        grid=QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel(""),0,0)
        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Zoom"),1,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.slider,2,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.zoomLabel,3,1)
        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel(""),4,0)
        grid.setRowMinimumHeight(0,55)
        grid.setRowMinimumHeight(4,55)
        grid.setSpacing(0)
        #slider setup#

        #scrollArea setup#
        scrollArea=QtGui.QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        scrollArea.setWidget(self.graph)
        scrollArea.setMaximumHeight(270)
        scrollArea.setMinimumWidth(600)
        #scrollarea setup#

        #layout setup
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(0)
        hbox.setSpacing(5)
        hbox.addWidget(scrollArea)
        hbox.addLayout(grid)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        #layout setup#

    def sliderValueChange(self):
        if self.graph.lista!=[]:
            self.graph.setSize(50+(len(self.graph.lista)/float(self.slider.value())))
        self.graph.setSizeDivision(1/float(self.slider.value()))
        self.graph.setZoom(50*self.slider.value())
        self.zoomLabel.setText(str(self.slider.value())+"x")
        self.graph.repaint()
```

The graph widget is resizable but if i set the line bellow to true, the scroll bar won't work at all.

```
scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
```

I've already checked others questions with this problem but did not work for me. So, setting the widget resizable to false makes the scroll bar work, except for the related problem i'm having.

The following code can reproduce the scroll area problem mentioned.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import GraphWidget

#graph data
graphList=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]*50

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    graphW=GraphWidget.graphWidget()
    graphW.graph.setLista(graphList)
    graphW.graph.setSize(50+len(graphList))
    graphW.graph.repaint()
    graphW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The codes and the file in theses links below are needed to make it work.

[CreateGraphFromInputs.py](https://pastebin.com/Kv6j22Ks)

[DrawGraph.py](https://pastebin.com/MbPuH28D)

[ListCleaning.py](https://pastebin.com/AdfPdjTH)

[ConfigGraphFile.py](https://pastebin.com/HaDPxQYF)

[graphWidget.py](https://pastebin.com/cwKT7Afn)

[configGraphFile](https://pastebin.com/22NEyDUa)

Comment: I wanted to reproduce your problem but I get the following error:  NameError: name 'CreateGraphFromInputs' is not defined

Comment: All the files needed to run the code and the code posted are in the links bellow:

[CreateGraphFromInputs.py](https://pastebin.com/Kv6j22Ks)
[DrawGraph.py](https://pastebin.com/MbPuH28D)
[ListCleaning.py](https://pastebin.com/AdfPdjTH)
[ConfigGraphFile.py](https://pastebin.com/HaDPxQYF)
[graphWidget.py](https://pastebin.com/cwKT7Afn)
[configGraphFile](https://pastebin.com/22NEyDUa)

Comment: Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: mmmm, that module requires other modules. Do you think I can reproduce your code like that? in SO we need a [mcve], take time and create it.

Comment: I downloaded your code, when I execute it I get the widget with a black background, you could tell me how it is done so that the graph of the signal you show is displayed.

Comment: yes same.Only the dark greenish black background with the slider and no other widgets

Comment: I see the curve when I move the horizontal scrollbar, but to do this you must place scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False), but what I do not like is that the drawing is very slow, it seems to me that the method you use to paint is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the solution. The problem was that the graph was not being resized correctly. In the [DrawGraph.py](https://pastebin.com/MbPuH28D) file, i was setting the geometry instead of resizing it.

So, i just changed this code line

```
self.setGeometry(0,0,self.size,self.height)
```

to this one

```
self.resize(self.size,self.height)
```

and now its working fine.